# What is the best way to implement a tree menu with a non-normalized register in C #?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I am trying to create a menu with a series of non-normalized records

The records would come as follows

SPORT |      LEAGUE |         MATCH|

Sport1 League1 Match1

Sport1 League1 Match2

Sport1 League2 Match1

Sport2 League1 Match1

And I was trying to avoid having to do a recursion using linq

Since it is currently being done in the following way

```
sportMenu.GroupBy(x => x.Sport)
         .Select(x => MenuItem.Create(x.Key, 
                      x.GroupBy(x => x.League)
                      .Select(x => MenuItem.Create(x.Key, x.GroupBy(x => x.Match)
                                                           .Select( x =>MenuItem.Create(x.Key, new List<MenuItem>()))))
                      .ToList()));

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> SubMenuItems { get; set; }}
    
    public static MenuItem Create(string name, List<MenuItem> subMenuItems)
    {
        return new MenuItem(name.Trim(), subMenuItems);
    }
    private MenuItem(string name, List<MenuItem> subMenuItems)
    {
        Name = name;
      }
}
```

If it is not understood very well, or some detail is needed, I remain pending.

Comment: What is wrong with recursion? It is proper way to work with trees. Your grouping code also looks good. What is the question?

Comment: My question is if there is a better way to implement this

Comment: LINQ is good in this case.